# Can't open shared library

Tags: mysql, c

I am trying to add a function i wrote in C  into MySql, in the function I am using '**gmp**' library, it compiles correctly and I copy the '**.so**' file to '**/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/**' and then log in to mysql and write '`CREATE FUNCTION MyFunc  RETURNS STRING SONAME "MyFunc.so";`' and I get the following error

> ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'MyFunc.so' (errno: 0
>   /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/MyFunc.so: undefined symbol: __gmpz_tdiv_q)

Any suggestions?.